# how can I get a MessageReader from protobuf.ByteString in java

Tags: capnproto

In Java Client I  get a

```java
com.google.protobuf.ByteString capn_object_bytes =   response.getCapnObject();
```

from C++ Server, and I want read the `Capn` Object  from `protobuf.ByteString`

@Kenton Varda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ByteString#asReadOnlyByteBuffer()` to get a `ByteBuffer`, which you can then read into Cap'n Proto:

```
MessageReader message =
    org.capnproto.Serialize.read(capn_object_bytes.asReadOnlyByteBuffer());
```

Comment: when in c++ server kj::ArrayPtr<const kj::ArrayPtr<const capnp::word>> segments = message.getSegmentsForOutput();    and java client do like this happen error   MessageReader message =
    org.capnproto.Serialize.read(capn_object_bytes.asReadOnlyByteBuffer());

Comment: @whutbd `getSegmentsForOutput()` only returns the segment array, which is *not* the complete serialized message. A serialized message needs to be prefixed with a segment table that indicates the size of each segment. That said, if you're able to transmit the segments and keep track of their sizes in your own way, so that you have a `ByteBuffer[]` in Java containing all the segments, then you can pass that directly to `MessageReader`'s constructor in Java.

Answer (score 0):

when in c++ server
 kj::ArrayPtr> segments = message.getSegmentsForOutput();

and java client do like this happen error
 MessageReader message = org.capnproto.Serialize.read(capn_object_bytes.asReadOnlyByteBuffer());